# Attribute Mapping MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, area

I am currently involved in a new **MVC 5** project an looking to map domains to MVC areas.

For example the following sites should map the their areas:

```
www.sitea.com needs to map to area SiteA
www.siteB.com needs to map to area SiteB
www.siteC.com needs to map to area SiteC
```

Is there an easier way to do this in **MVC 5** using attribute mapping, or does one still need to look at using something similar to the IRouteConstraint interface

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean attribute routing, unfortunately not. The purpose of introducing attribute routing in MVC 5 is to co-locate routing configuration with controller's actions to ease reasoning about mapping between URI's and actions.

The new functionality of attribute routing still revolves around `VirtualPathData` class, which constrains you to use tokens only from the virtual path. Mapping hostname to area exceeds boundary of declarative routing even in MVC 5 and you would have to extend infrastructure in a solution close to [Implementing ASP.NET MVC Domain Routing by Maarten Balliauw](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx).

You could of course try to inherit from `RouteAttribute`, `RouteAreaAttribute` and the like but IMHO you would end up at implementation similar to above.